# Javascript Scrolling Tables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a certain view of some editable data (for a timesheet system) and the piece I am currently working on needs to be scrollable in a certain way.  It is unlikely that this will need to scroll vertically, but it will need to move horizontally.  I have the table in a separate div with auto overflow, but I have no idea how to proceed.  I would appreciate any help.

As requested, the code follows, but there isn't much to show.  I have no access to any CSS, due to corporate restrictions on the server.  The content of the row is created by a Javascript function (at this point, it simply creates 40 identical `<td>` elements with a width set to 30 and an integer value 1 - 40 to make sure the table is wide enough to require scrolling).  No matter what the width of the `<td>` elements is set to, the div just compresses them.

```
<div id='TimeScroller' width='100%' style='overflow:auto;'>
    <table id='TimeData'>
        <tr id='Days' style='font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace; font-size: 11px;'>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:** I am having this problem again.  I tried the solution listed below, but no luck.  Instead, I managed to find a way not to need this scrolling functionality.  Unfortunately, my new project requires me to figure it out, so I have to solve the problem after all.  The code I am using is as follows:

```
<td>
    <div id='am_scheduleScroller' style='overflow: auto;'>
        <table id='am_scheduleDisplay' width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='empty-cells: show;'>
            <thead>
                <tr id='am_schedule_formatBar'></tr>
                <tr id='am_schedule_tableTitleBar'></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</td>


var totalDays;

$(document).ready(function() {
    var today = new Date();
    $('#am_monthSelector_from').val(today.getMonth() + 1).prop('selected', true);
    $('#am_yearSelector_from').val(today.getFullYear()).prop('selected', true);

    getDates();
    loadData();
});


function getDates() {
    var moLen = new Array();
    var moSelFrom = $('#am_monthSelector_from').val();
    var moSelTo = $('#am_monthSelector_to').val();
    var yrSelFrom = $('#am_yearSelector_from').val();
    var yrSelTo = $('#am_yearSelector_to').val();
    var months = new Array();
    var firstDay;
    var firstDate = '';
    totalDays = 0;

    var mo = moSelFrom;
    var yr = yrSelFrom;
    // Grab the length of the previous month (for the weekly divisions)
    if(mo == 1) {
        mo = 12;
        yr--;
    } else
        mo--;

    // Collect month lengths
    var index = 0;
    while(yr < yrSelTo || mo < moSelTo) {
        months[index] = mo;
        moLen[index] = new Date(yr, mo, 0).getDate();
        if(mo == 12) {
            mo = 0;
            yr++;
        }
        mo++;
        index++;
    }
    months[index] = moSelTo;
    moLen[index] = new Date(yrSelTo, moSelTo, 0).getDate();


    // Decide first day for week listings (title row)
    firstDay = new Date(yrSelFrom, months[1], 1).getDay();
    if(firstDay != 1) {
        totalDays += +firstDay - 1;
        firstDay = (moLen[0] - firstDay) + 2;
        firstDate = months[0] + ' / ' + firstDay + ' / ' + yrSelFrom;
    } else
        firstDate = months[1] + ' / 1 / ' + yrSelFrom;

    for(var i = 1; i < moLen.length; i++) {
        totalDays += moLen[i];
    }

    // Schedule formatting row
    var dateList = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < totalDays; i++)
        dateList = dateList + '<td style="width:30px;"></td>';
    $('#am_schedule_formatBar').html(dateList);


    // Date row (divided into weeks)
    var moIndex = 1;
    var day = 8;
    yr = yrSelFrom;
    if(firstDay != 1) {
        day = 7 - (moLen[0] - firstDay);
    }
    dateList = '<td style="width:30px; border: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 2px solid black;" id="am_date_0" align="center" colspan="7">' + firstDate + '</td>';
    for(var i = 7; i < totalDays; i += 7) {
        dateList = dateList + '<td style="width:30px; border: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 2px solid black;" id="am_date_' + i + '" align="center" colspan="7">' + months[moIndex] + ' / ' + day + ' / ' + yr + '</td>';
        day += 7;
        if(day > moLen[moIndex]) {
            day = day - moLen[moIndex];
            if(moIndex == 12) {
                yr++;
                moIndex = 1;
            } else 
                moIndex++;
        }
    }

    $('#am_schedule_tableTitleBar').html(dateList);
    $('#am_resource_tableTitleBar').html('<td><b>Employee:</b></td>');
}


function loadData() {
    var data = '<tr>';

    for(var i = 0; i < totalDays; i++) {
        data = data + '<td align="center" id="am_sched_' + empID + '_' + date + '" align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;"></td>';
    }
    data = data + '</tr>';

    $('#am_scheduleDisplay tbody').html(data);
    $('#am_resourceList tbody').html('<tr><td>' + empID + ':' + empName + '</td></tr>');


    var startElt = $('#am_sched_' + empID + '_' + start);
    startElt
        .html('Out')
        .attr('colspan',length)
        .css('backgroundColor', '#00FFFF')
        .closest('tbody');


    var prevElt = startElt.next();
    startElt = prevElt.next();
    for(var i = 1; i < length; i++) {
        prevElt.remove();
        prevElt = startElt;
        startElt = startElt.next();
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: add some code so we can help please

Comment: Try [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid).

Comment: Your table is already in DIV with `overflow:auto` - if it grows bigger than the DIV - don't scrollbars appear?

Comment: Post your code here please.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<div id='TimeScroller'style='overflow:auto;width:100%'>
    <table id='TimeData' style="table-layout:fixed; width:100%">
        <tr id='Days' style='font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace; font-size: 11px;'>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This sort of worked, but it's not a solution I can use.  I can't use a fixed size for this application, as it needs to adjust to various window sizes.  Also, it causes the width setting in the `td` elements to be ignored- they automatically fill the div, and the specified width of the elements does nothing to force the div to scroll.

Comment: You may have to use client-side code to automatically resize DIV based on current window width, you cannot use percentage if you want scrolling to work. About `td` - do you use `width` attribute or width in a style?

Comment: I use width style for the `<td>` elements.

Comment: Try giving your table `style="table-layout:fixed; width:100%"`. I think now you can give your DIV style width:100% as well (updated my answer with full markup)